# How to deal with client and server sockets using shared library .so format both having main()?

Tags: c++, sockets, shared-libraries

Scenario is like this: I have php page which sends sentence to the client.cpp. Client.cpp should send req to server.cpp(obviously server needs to listen all the time).

Both client and server have `main()` function. server.cpp has some other function which processes the sentence rec from client and sends 2 `int` values back.

Now client.cpp stores this recv two numbers and gives it to php file which will store this values in db

I want to have .sl file for client.cpp. php file will make request to this .sl file. But for client's .sl file to run server need to be in listening mode all the time.

In which format should I keep the server.cpp file so that it will listen the req coming from client.sl and reply back.? I kept .sl file of server, i does not work.

Any idea how to deal this complex scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared library would not have file with main() function.
After creating shared library we have to create c program with main function which which will call main() function and perform specific task!